# How to make child content vertically in center as respect to parent container in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I have been trying to make my child content vertically centered as per the parent container. But the child container is always in relative to parent container. Below is the code I have tried:

**HTML**

```
<section id="welcome" class="bg-primary d-flex flex-column">
        <h1>Positions</h1>
        <div class="container text-center my-auto">
           Centered content
        </div>
     </section>
```

**CSS**

```
      #welcome{
        min-height:150px;
        width: 200px;
     }
```

What I am looking is to make **Centered Content** text vertically centered as per the whole section.

Here is the codepen link: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXpmyw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `h1` `position-absolute` to remove it from relative positioning within the DOM...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeVXbe

```
<section id="welcome" class="bg-primary d-flex flex-column">
      <h1 class="position-absolute">Positions</h1>
      <div class="container text-center my-auto">
           Centered content
      </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your h1 element is what's causing it to mis-align. If you get rid of it (just to test) you'll see centered content move to the center.

**display: flex;** applies to all of that elements direct children, so you're aligning to aggregate height of both the h1 and the #welcome element. To have Centered Content in the center of a tall square, you could apply some of the styles you have on #welcome to .my-auto:

```
.my-auto {
  min-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
}
```

**align-items** is what does vertical alignment when using display: flex. However, if you use flex-direction: column, the direction is "rotated", so you would use justify-content: center, which is normally for horizontal alignment.

A different approach is to use padding on top and bottom of the content you want to center:

```
.my-auto {
  padding: 50px 0; /* 50px is an arbitrary number, just to demonstrate */
}
```

Note that this will cause centered content to push all other elements vertically away from it.

Comment: I know on removing the h1 tag brings the content to center but I need that title to be placed there as per design. Do u have any solution

Comment: Then I think I would use padding on top and bottom of the content you want centered, because with flexbox, everything inside that #welcome div will be affected.